# Reason for "K cannot be used to index type" in these cases

Tags: typescript, types

TypeScript Version: 4.1.5 (strict mode)

### My Issue

There is an element to TypeScript's type system that I appear to be missing here.

I'm not sure why, in the following cases, I get the corresponding TypeScript errors. I suspect there's some equivalence between them.

Notice how, in getOption 1, 2 and 3, TypeScript produce errors. But, in getOption 4 and 5, there is no such error. Please could anybody help me understand why in this case, there are errors in 1-3, but not 4-5.

### Use Case

I want to have derived classes of A that include an extended Options property, using an extended Options interface. And I'd like the method in the base class to always infer the types associated with the current instance in the call context.

### Demonstration

```
interface Options {
    test: boolean;
}

class A {
    private options: Options;
    
    constructor(options: Options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    
    // Setting the 'this' arg doesn't change anything
    getOptions(this: A): Options {
        return this.options;
    }
    
    // Doesn't work - TS2536: Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'Options'.
    getOption1<O extends Options, K extends keyof O>(name: K): O[K] {
        const options = this.getOptions();
        
        return options[name];
    }

    // Doesn't work - TS2536: Type 'keyof ReturnType' cannot be used to index type 'Options'.
    getOption2(name: keyof ReturnType<this['getOptions']>): ReturnType<this['getOptions']>[keyof ReturnType<this['getOptions']>] {
        const options = this.getOptions();
        
        return options[name];
    }

    // Doesn't work - two of the same error:
    // TS2536: Type 'keyof ReturnType' cannot be used to index type 'Options'.
    getOption3(name: keyof ReturnType<this['getOptions']>): Options[typeof name] {
        const options = this.getOptions();
        
        // TS2536: Type 'keyof ReturnType ' cannot be used to index type 'Options'.
        return options[name];
    }

    // Works
    getOption4(name: keyof Options): Options[typeof name] {
        const options = this.getOptions();

        return options[name];
    }

    // Works
    getOption5(name: keyof Options): ReturnType<this['getOptions']>[typeof name] {
        const options = this.getOptions();

        return options[name];
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that options can also be a subtype and therefor won't match the other options type.

This works:

```
interface Options {
    test: boolean;
}

class A {
    private options: Options;
    
    constructor(options: Options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    
    // Setting the 'this' arg doesn't change anything
    getOptions(this: A): Options {
        return this.options;
    }
    
    getOption1<O extends Options, K extends keyof O>(name: K): O[K] {
        const options = this.getOptions() as O;
        
        return options[name];
    }

    getOption2(name: keyof ReturnType<this['getOptions']>): ReturnType<this['getOptions']>[keyof ReturnType<this['getOptions']>] {
        const options = this.getOptions() as ReturnType<this['getOptions'];
        
        return options[name];
    }

    getOption3(name: keyof ReturnType<this['getOptions']>): ReturnType<this['getOptions']>[typeof name] {
        const options = this.getOptions() as ReturnType<this['getOptions']>;
        
        // TS2536: Type 'keyof ReturnType ' cannot be used to index type 'Options'.
        return options[name];
    }

    // Works
    getOption4(name: keyof Options): Options[typeof name] {
        const options = this.getOptions();

        return options[name];
    }

    // Works
    getOption5(name: keyof Options): ReturnType<this['getOptions']>[typeof name] {
        const options = this.getOptions();

        return options[name];
    }
}
```

But in this specific case you'd probably want to create a generic class parameter for the options:

```
class A<TOptions extends Options> {
    private options: TOptions;
    
    constructor(options: TOptions) {
        this.options = options;
    }
    
    getOptions(): TOptions {
        return this.options;
    }
    
    getOption<K extends keyof TOptions>(name: K): TOptions[K] {
        const options = this.getOptions();
        
        return options[name];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah - I see! this.getOptions() could be overridden in derived classes to return a different subtype. I was using your suggested fix where I'd encountered this, but thought maybe I was missing something that meant it isn't necessary.

Comment: Yeah, in a derrived class you can indeed return a different subtype. In this case you probaly want to make the options property generic (see the updated answer)

Comment: Thank you! I did do this initially, but that brought along a similar set of challenges related to calls to various functions and methods where the type argument could be set to a subtype. In the end, it seemed the least abrasive approach was to "trust" derived classes not to override a particular method. I'll try this out again and see if maybe I was just massively misunderstanding/abusing a TypeScript feature, which seems probable here!